# Why add 1 when converting from 2's complement back to decimal?

Tags: twos-complement

When we want to show **8-bit** binary representations of a negative number **-123** in **two’s complement**  we do:

Number in decimal = **-123**

1. Convert -123 to its absolute value: **123**
2. Covert to binary: **01111011**
3. One's complement it: **10000100**
4. Add 1: **10000101**
5. Check:

| 2^7 | 2^6 | 2^5 | 2^4 | 2^3 | 2^2 | 2^1 | 2^0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 64 | 32 | 16 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| 128 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 |

But since the first bit is to represent a negative sign we take it as **-128** instead of 128 and add them all up.

- Therefore: **(-128)+4+1 = -123**

But why does every online 2's complement calculator give the answer as **0111 1011**?

Comment: What do you mean by "every online 2's complement calculator". The ones I checked return the correct value `1000 0101` for the number `-123`. The sequence `0111 1011` is for the number `123`.

Comment: I checked on [allmath](https://www.allmath.com/twos-complement.php), [calculator-online](https://calculator-online.net/twos-complement-calculator/) and [omnicalculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/twos-complement). All return the answer as 0111 1011.

Comment: There is a difference in calculating the bit-representation of a number in the format of "Two's complement" and "getting the Two's complement" of a number like the "negative" of a number. https://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/ will show you that the bit-representation of `-123` in "Two's complement" is `1000 0101`, the others will show you how to get the complementary of a given number (as in multiply by `-1`). Check the comment at the bottom of https://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/